# Animate insertion of cells at bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm making a `UIViewController` to manage a messaging screen. I'm doing this using a `UITableView` and some custom cells.

To make things simpler, each cell contains:

- Its chat "bubble" (a `UIView` subclass)
- Its chat text (a `UILabel`)
- A timestamp header label (which might be hidden)
- A bottom footer label (for "Sending...", "Delivered", etc.; also might be hidden)

Because of performance concerns, I am not using auto-sizing of cell heights, but caching cell heights into an `NSMutableDictionary`.

When the user sends or receives a new message, I want the following to occur:

1. The current last message cell is reloaded, hiding its bottom label, if needed.
2. The new last message cell is appended at the bottom of the `UITableView`.
3. The `UITableView` is scrolled so that the new last cell is visible.

I can get it to where the end state of the screen is as desired, but the animations in between are really kinda funky. I have tried a whole lot of different approaches to get the animations to behave. Basically, it seems like some major reloading is happening, even though the only cell that could **possibly** change its height is the last cell (prior to the insertion of the new cell). Plus, I'd like to have the last cell simply "appear" in place without animation. If it does, it should be off-screen, and then I should be able to animate it on-screen.

Here's my current "user sent a new message" method:

```
- (IBAction)sendButtonPressed {
    //Creation of the new message, into 'message' variable

    [self.messages          addObject:message];

    int thisIndex           = (int)self.messages.count - 1;
    NSIndexPath *this       = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:thisIndex inSection:0];
    int prevIndex           = (int)self.messages.count - 2;
    NSIndexPath *prev       = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:prevIndex inSection:0];
    [self removeCachedHeightForIndex:prevIndex];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[prev] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[this] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
    }];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

This appears to reload the last several cells in the `UITableView`. Or, at least, every cell that is visible when this is called seems to be animated in some way. Only the cell at `prev` is actually changing in any way.

Longterm, I might pull out the header and footer labels into different cells, but is there a way to fix this animation glitch as-is?

Comment: You may be over-complicating things... Assuming you have an array holding all of the "messages" (so you can populate the table in the first place), try simply adding the new message data to your array, calling `reloadData()` on the table view, and then scroll to bottom.

Comment: @DonMag I thought of that. For some reason, that doesn't quite work. The contentOffset seems to get a bit screwy, and the "scrollToBottom" part doesn't end up working quite right.

Comment: When doing that, are you waiting for the next update before calling scroll to bottom?

Comment: @DonMag I think so. The `scrollToBottomAnimated:` method makes its animation call in a `dispatch_async` block. IIRC, that puts the block to be called into the run loop, but after the current loop, right?

Comment: hmm... too much for comments... chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151105/donmag

Comment: Can’t right now. Sorry. I have multiple animations, and I think they’re colliding. Will check later and report back.